# Windows Form Not Returning Correct Value from Public Method

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have three classes, code provided below.

Network - Add and Remove Phone, Process Calls
Phone1 and Phone2 can call each other when added to the network.

But I am having issue when I am connecting both phone to the network and trying to call phone1 to phone2, it is keep giving me "receiver busy". I have tried to do little debugging and read status of phone2 when calling from phone1 but it returns an empty string (Which should actually return "A", when it is added to the network).

Any help would much appreciated.

-----Networks Class------------------

```
namespace Demo
{
    public partial class network : Form
    {
        phone1 p1 = new phone1();
        phone2 p2 = new phone2();
        public network()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Boolean numberValidator(int number)
        {

            Boolean exist = false;
            if (comboBox2.Items.Equals(number))
            {
                exist = true;
            }

            return exist;
        }

        public void processCall(int rNumber)

        {

            if (!numberValidator(rNumber))
            {
                p1.TextBox1.Clear();
                p1.TextBox1.Text = "Not connected";

                //MessageBox.Show(p2.returnPhoenStatus());
            }

            else
            {

                    p1.TextBox1.Clear();

                    p1.TextBox1.Text = "Call in progress";

                    p2.receiveCall(1);

                    p1.setStatus("Busy");
                    /*
                    if (p2.btnCallPressStatus())
                    {
                        p1.TextBox1.Clear();

                        p1.TextBox1.Text = "Call initiated";
                    }*/

             }


           }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                p1.Show();
                comboBox2.Items.Add(1);
                p1.setStatus("A");
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                p2.Show();
                comboBox2.Items.Add(2);
                p2.setStatus("A");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

----------Phone1 Class---------

```
namespace Demo
{
    public partial class phone1 : Form
    {
        public phone1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }




        string status;

        public void setStatus(string Status)
        {
            status = Status;
        }

        public string returnStatus()
        {
            return status;
        }

        public void receiveCall(int callerNumber)
        {
            setStatus("Busy");

            btnCall.Text = "Answer";

            textBox1.Text = "Phone " + callerNumber + " Calling.";

        }

        public void makeCall(int number)
        {
            phone2 p2 = new phone2();
            network net = new network();

            MessageBox.Show(p2.returnStatus()); // this line not returing status of phone2
            if (p2.returnStatus() == "A")
            {
                net.processCall(number);
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Receiver Busy";
            }


        }

        public TextBox TextBox1
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox1;
            }
        }

        private void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string number = textBox1.Text;
            int numberInt = Convert.ToInt16(number);


            makeCall(numberInt);
        }

        string phoneNo = "";
        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            phoneNo = phoneNo + btn2.Text;

            textBox1.Text = phoneNo;
        }
    }
}
```

-------------phone2 Class--------------

```
namespace Demo
{
    public partial class phone2 : phone1
    {
        public phone2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piyush has the right answer, but I thought I'd add this answer as a handy hint to avoid this kind of error.

Try writing your `button1_Click` method like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    var p = (new [] { p1, p2 })[i]; // Or `var p = i == 0 ? p1 : p2;`

    p.Show();
    comboBox2.Items.Add(i + 1);
    p.setStatus("A");
}
```

This way you avoid the code duplication and the mistyping that occurred.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I was looking something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are setting the status of P1 both the times. Check this if condition in button1_Click method in network class. The setStatus should be for P2.

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                p2.Show();
                comboBox2.Items.Add(2);
                p2.setStatus("A");
            }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. but even after what you suggested I am unable to call phone2 from phone1. as mentioned earlier I am trying to MessageBox.Show(p2.returnStatus()); in network class which should return "A" but its returning an empty string.

Comment: no, no luck yet!! This is really strange, everything seems fine but for some reason, it is not working. I am keep going through the code again and again but still no luck.